# Navicon Transformicons - Middle Line Not Clickable

Tags: html, css, debugging, hyperlink

I have no idea why this navicon (copied from  https://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/twbyA ) works perfectly except for the middle line which is not clickable.

I do have to have a z-index set for the page, so I thought it might be that but even when I remove all the z-indexes I still can't click the middle line. I'm not sure what to even be looking for that could cause behavior like this so any pointers that could help me understand what is causing this would be greatly appreciated!

Markup:

```
    <div class="top-bar-right float-right navicon-button-wrapper">
        <a class="navicon-button x" id="navicon-button">
          <div class="navicon"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

SCC:

```
$duration: .5s;

$size : 100%;
$toggled-size : .75;

$bg : #274380;
$nav-bg  : #000;
$content-bg : #FFF;

.navicon-button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2.0625rem 1.5rem;
  transition: $duration/2;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  opacity: .8;

  .navicon:before, .navicon:after {
    transition: $duration/2;
  }

  &:hover {
    transition: $duration;
    opacity: 1;

    .navicon:before, .navicon:after {
      transition: $duration/2;
    }

    .navicon:before { top: .825rem; }
    .navicon:after { top: -.825rem; }
  }
}

.navicon {
  position: relative;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: .3125rem;
  background: $content-bg;
  transition: $duration;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;

  &:before, &:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: .3125rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    background: $content-bg;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: $duration $duration/2;
    border-radius: 1rem;
  }

  &:before { top: .625rem; }
  &:after { top: -.625rem; }
}

.open:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.open:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0 !important;
}

.open .navicon:before,
.open .navicon:after {
  transition: $duration;
}

/* × and + */
.open.plus,
.open.x {
  .navicon {
    background: transparent;

    &:before { transform: rotate(-45deg); }
    &:after { transform: rotate(45deg); }
  }
}
.open.plus { 
  transform: scale($toggled-size) rotate(45deg) 
}

.navicon-button-wrapper
{
display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  // height: 4.5rem;
  // background: $nav-bg;
  // text-align: right;
  // border-radius: .5rem .5rem 0 0;
  // padding: 0 1rem;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: The code you post here works ... so it's impossible what is wrong on your implementation https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYzJMd

Comment: Yes, the code in the codepen works in codepen. It doesn't when I copy/paste into my local build, so that's why I'm asking what could cause behavior like I listed.